# Prove that $f(n)=n$, $\forall n \in \mathbb N$ for the strictly increasing multiplicative function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, induction, contest-math, functional-equations

### Problem

Let $f : \mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a strictly increasing function such that $f(2) = 2$ and $f(mn) = f(m) \cdot f(n)$ for every relatively prime pair of positive integers $m$ and $n$. Prove that $f(n) = n$ for every positive integer $n$.

### My approach

I tried to prove this using induction. For the base case, we need to find $f(3)$. We have $$f(3) \cdot f(5)<2f(9)<4f(5)$$ $$\implies f(3)<4$$ And since $f(3)>f(2)=2$, we have $f(3)=3$.
Now, we assume that $f(k-1)=k-1$ and $f(k)=k$. Since $k$ and $k-1$ are relatively prime, we have $f(k(k-1))=f(k)f(k-1)=k(k-1)$. But this does not prove.

---

So, how do I complete the proof?

Comment: It is strictly increasing. If you know $f(2) = 2$ and $f(10) = 10$, can you say something about the function in the interval (2,10)? Try to think how to apply this to end your solution.

Comment: You can actually know that $f(x) = x$ in that interval. Think about it this way: You have $3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ in that interval. The image of $f$ in that interval, by the inequality you have written, must be $3,4,5,6,7,8,9$. And you know $f(3) < f(4) < f(5) < f(6) < f(7) < f(8) < f(9)$. So neccesarily $f(x)$ must be exactly $x$ in the interval. You can argue formally this by the pigeonhole principle or by contradiction, but the idea is that.

Comment: This can be generalized: if you have $f(a) = a, f(b) = b$ and $f$ is strictly increasing over the natural numbers, then $f(x) = x$ in $[a,b]$. This little exercise allow you to finish your exercise, thanks to your last equality.

Comment: @AnilCh Iterating $k \mapsto k(k - 1)$ will be unbounded and thus, prove it for all of $\Bbb N$, so that would finish the problem. Maybe you could post it as an answer.

Comment: This is Erdos Theorem: Let $f:\textbf{Z}^+\rightarrow \textbf{R}$ be a multiplicvative function. If $f$ is non-decraesing, then exists $a\in\textbf{R}$ such that $f(n)=n^a$, $\forall n \in\textbf{Z}^{+}$.

Comment: For proof see:  https://www.jstor.org/stable/2322314

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $(a_n)$ be a strictly increasing sequence of positive integers such that: $a_2 = 2$, $a_{mn} = a_m a_n$ for $m, n$ relatively prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3331675/let-a-n-be-a-strictly-increasing-sequence-of-positive-integers-such-that-a). The other post is basically the same as this one except it uses a sequence of positive integers $a_n$ instead of an integer function.

Comment: @NikosBagis This has $\mathbb{N}$ as range.

Comment: @AnilCh. $\textbf{Z}^{+}=\textbf{N}$. See also my link.

Comment: @NikosBagis I don't know if I'm misreading something here, but I said range, not domain. You've written $R$, which makes the problem much, much harder than what it actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show this little lemma previously: If $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is a strictly increasing function over naturals and we have $a,b\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $f(a) = a, f(b) = b$ then $f(x) = x $ for all naturals in the interval $[a,b]$.

Proof of the lemma: Let $S$ be the set of naturals $S = \{a+1, ..., b-1\}$. Because $f$ is strictly increasing, we have $a < f(a+1) < f(a+2) < ... < f(b-1) < b$. In particular this means $f(S) = S$. Furthermore, $f(a+1)$ is the minimum of all values, because all those must be different it must mean that $f(a+1) = a+1$ because that's the minimum of $S$. If it wasn't $a+1$ you can reach a contradiction, because there must be a number in $S$ with image $a+1$. You can finish by applying this result to $f(a+1) = a+1, f(b) = b$.

After that you just apply your induction solution with $f(2) = 2$ and $f(k(k-1)) = k(k-1)$.